# Passing array of object through protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I keep hit the same error: `keyOrObj.hasOwnProperty is not a function`.

data to pass

```
{
  "stocks": [{
    "quantity":3,
    "substore_uuid": "2343423443423"
  }]
}
```

and here is my proto declaration

```
service Procurement {
  rpc distributeUpsert (ProcurementStockDistributionUpsertReq) returns (ProcurementStockDistributionRes) {}
}

message ProcurementStockDistributionUpsertReq {
  message ProcurementStockDistributionUpsertReqInput {
    string uuid = 1;
    int32 quantity = 2;
    string procurement_detail_uuid = 3;
    string distribution_officer_uuid = 4;
    string substore_uuid = 5;
  }
  repeated ProcurementStockDistributionUpsertReqInput stocks = 1;
}
```

here the code that trigger the error

```
const protoArgs = cloneDeep({
   stocks: [...args.stocks.map(stock => stock)],
});
svc.SM.Procurement.distributeUpsert(
   protoArgs,
   (err, response = {}) => {
      if (err) {
         reject(err);
         return;
      }
      resolve(response);
   },
);
```

Do I have to use stream as shown [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/protos/route_guide.proto#L46). Any advice?

Comment: Can you show the code that is triggering that error?